# How to export data sources in Weblogic 12.1.1

Tags: web, server, weblogic, datasource, web.xml

I am running a Linux Red hat and am currently in process of replicating a running WLS server and one problem I have come to is having to recreate data sources. the pack/unpack command does not satisfy my needs, as it does not export data sources. I want to avoid having to manually recreate the Data sources, as this way is more prone to error. Is there a way how to easily export the already set up data sources to my new server?

Comment: you can also zip your domain and unzip it on your target machine.

Comment: hello, thanks for tip, I tried that but in many files and starting scripts there are absolute paths, so just plain zipping and unpacking it is an impossible option for me.